# UWP ListView within a NavigationView, only first child rendered

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I would like to have a NavigationView with some more elements slightly more complex than the common `NavigationViewItem`. To be more specific, my goal is to have a `ListView` somewhere in the middle of my `NavigationView`, just after the `NavigationView.MenuItems` section. But for some reasons, when I try to use a `ListView` (or `StackPanel`), only the first child is rendered.

Some XAML reproducing this issue:

```xml
<NavigationView x:Name="mainNavigation" PaneDisplayMode="Left" ItemInvoked="OnNavigationViewItemInvoked" Loaded="OnNavigationViewLoaded">
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItemHeader Content="Favorites" />
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Space 1" />
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Space 2" />
        <NavigationViewItemSeparator Margin="0,0,0,20" />

        <NavigationViewItem>
            <AutoSuggestBox QueryIcon="Find" PlaceholderText="Search for a space" Width="288" />
        </NavigationViewItem>
        <NavigationViewItem>
            <ListView>
                <ListViewItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Test1" />
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Test2" />
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Test3" />
                </ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
        </NavigationViewItem>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>

    <Frame x:Name="rootFrame" />
</NavigationView>
```

Which render to:

[image]

As you can see in this screenshot, only the first child ("Test1") is visible, "Test2" and "Test3" aren't rendered for reasons I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `ListViewItem` is a fixed height. You can change this by updating the template in-line in the XAML:

```
<NavigationViewItem>
  <NavigationViewItem.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
      <Border Height="auto">
        <ContentPresenter/>
      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </NavigationViewItem.Template>
  <ListView>
    <!-- your items -->
  </ListView>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, that works. Is there some details on this somewhere in Microsoft online documentation? That seems like obscure arcane knowledge to me :)
Though I'm of course quite new to XAML, that's maybe something well known by more experienced people.